# Split String on JButton press

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

I am trying to make the input from a JTextField get split into an array of words when I press a button.  When I press the button the program gives me a huge list of errors.  The line of code that splits the sentence and where I call the class in the action listener is where eclipse says the error is coming from.  I do not know why I am getting this error and I don't know how to fix.  I have tried a lot of different things but they don't work.  If you could explain why this isn't working or how to fix that would be great.  Here is my code.  Thank you for your help.

**Main Class**:

```
public class Control {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OpenWindow ow = new OpenWindow();
        ow.window();
    } 
}
```

**Second Class**:

```
public class OpenWindow extends JFrame{
//Making variables
String input;
String firstWord2;
JButton jb = new JButton("Button");
JLabel jl = new JLabel();
JTextField jtf = new JTextField(40);
JPanel jp1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
SentenceSplitter ss = new SentenceSplitter();

public void window() {
    //Make window pop up
    setTitle("Project");
    setSize(600, 300);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //Action Listener
    jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            input = jtf.getText();
            //Error from line below
            ss.split();

            firstWord2 = ss.getFirstWord();

            jl.setText(firstWord2);
        }
    });
    //Add JFrames
    jp1.add(jtf);
    jp1.add(jb);
    jp1.add(jl);
    add(jp1);
}
//Make input accesible from other classes
String getInput() {
    return input;
}
}
```

**Third Class**:

```
public class SentenceSplitter {

String firstWord;

public void split() {

    OpenWindow ow2 = new OpenWindow();
    //Get input
    String sentence = ow2.getInput();
    //Error from line below
    String[] splitSentence = sentence.split(" ");

    firstWord = splitSentence[0];
}
String getFirstWord() {
    return firstWord;
}
}
```

Comment: Check and make sure that 'sentence' is not null.

Comment: The fact that you're creating a new `OpenWindow` in your `SentenceSplitter` looks like a problem. I would just make `split()` return something and accept a String as the input parameter. You could even make the method static and just use `SentenceSplitter` as a "util" class.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you

1. creating OpenWindow
2. In The OpenWindow object you are creating a `SentenceSplitter` and listening for a click
3. On the click you are calling the `split` method on the previously created `SentenceSplitter`
4. In split you are creating a new `OpenWindow`

What you maybe should do is pass the String as an input parameter to the `split` method

Comment: ah you beat me to it. Enjoy the rep.